# Haskell IO - read from standard input directly to list

Tags: haskell

Haskell IO system is super hard to understand for me so i have question : How to read from standard input to list ? I know that there is function getLine :: IO String and interact. But i do not know how to convert the input to list so I can use it in this three functions :

```
powerset []     = [[]]
powerset (x:xs) = xss ++ map (x:) xss
                               where xss = powerset xs
main = print $ powerset([1,2])

import Control.Monad(filterM)
p = filterM(const[True,False])
main = p[1,2]

main = subsequences([1,2])
```

I want to be able to write 1 2 3 and pass this values to the function. Can you tell/show how to do it ?

**Extra question**

Haskell is full of magic so i was wondering if it possible to use input directly in the function like this :

```
main = subsequences(some input magic here)
```

Comment: So you want to read a list of something from `stdin`? A list of what? Two things that might be useful: the `Read` class and `readList`.

Comment: What kind of input do you want to convert? How is it separated? What kind of data it is containing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may write:

```
main = readLn >>= print . subsequences
```

You will need to nail down the type to be read, for example by having a monomorphic `subsequences` or by annotating `readLn`. In ghci:

```
Data.List> (readLn :: IO [Integer]) >>= print . subsequences
[1,2,3]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

(I typed in the first and second lines -- both followed by enter -- and the third line was the result.)

For more details, you may enjoy one of the excellent resources below:

- [The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html)
- [You Could Have Invented Monads (And Maybe You Already Have)](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)
- [All About Monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads)

Comment: Thank You, your answer is really usefull ! But can You show me how to make it possible to run this in http://rextester.com/runcode ?

Comment: @Cosaquee Stick `import Data.List; main = (readLn :: IO [Integer]) >>= print . subsequences` in the code box and `[1,2,3]` in the input box, then hit "Run".

Comment: If i copy this into rextester it always show : Process killed, because it ran longer than 10 seconds. I`m starting to know how IO system is working thanks to your comments !

Comment: @Cosaquee I get that message if I don't put anything in the "input" box. Have you done that part?

Comment: Any option that i can just type  1 2 3 and it will use it as the input for subsequences ? Now i need to manually type the list.

Comment: @Cosaquee You can write a parser for just about any format you like. Give it a shot yourself; if you get stuck, details about what you tried and why you can't make progress would be fantastic material for a fresh question. Note that the parsing stage -- turning the `String` you get from input into an `[Integer]` to process -- has nothing to do with IO.